# R Extract rows where column greater than 40

Tags: r

Good day
I have a data set I got from a txt file

```
> MyData
   Xdat Ydat
1  1    12
2  2    23
3  3    34
4  4    45
5  5    56
6  6    67
7  7    78
```

I need to use this set to extract rows that correspond to the case where the 2nd column(Ydat) is greater than 40.
Resulting in
MyData2

```
   Xdat Ydat
4  4    45
5  5    56
6  6    67
7  7    78
```

Comment: `subset(MyDate, Ydat > 40)`

Comment: `df[df$Ydat > 40, ]`

Comment: `MyData[MyData$Ydat>40, ]` This is one of the most basic types of subsetting you can do in R. I strongly suggest you read a [basic introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html).

Answer (score 22):

Simple subsetting will do it -

```
MyData[which(MyData[,2]>40),]
```

as @DavidArenburg points out, this works fine:

```
MyData[(MyData[,2]>40),]
```

Comment: You really didn't make it simple as it should be...

Comment: ok. simple is relative.